# use javascript to produce php in html

Tags: php, javascript, html, performance

I am trying to create php script inside html tags by using javascript. The idea of it is, that when the user clicks a button, that will trigger the type of php script to produce and determine what is accessed from the database.

The problem I am having is whenever the javascript is executed, the written php comes out commented out like so `<!--?php [code] ?-->`. While what I have intentionally on the javascript is this `<?php [code] ?>`

So as you can see the tags are changed from script to comment html tags.

**javascript code**

```
function determineDisplay(display_id) {
    var phpO = "<?php echo ";
    var phpF = "read_home('" + display_id + "', '";
    var phpE = "'); ?>";

    var type = [];
    type[0] = "content_desc";
    type[1] = "content_img";
    var imgpath = "images/; ";
    type[2] = "content_comp";

//The alerts are to check what is inserted afterwords.

    document.getElementById(type[0]).innerHTML = phpO + phpF + type[0] + phpE;
alert(document.getElementById(type[0]).innerHTML);
    document.getElementById(type[1]).src = phpO + imgpath + phpF + type[1] + phpE;
alert(document.getElementById(type[1]).src);
    document.getElementById(type[2]).innerHTML = phpO + phpF + type[2] + phpE;
alert(document.getElementById(type[2]).innerHTML);
}
```

**html code**(The html has a default php, but by using the javascript, it is changed.

```
<table width="696px" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><font size="-1" id="content_desc">
            <?php read_home('a', 'content_desc'); ?>
        </font></td>
        <td>
        <img id="content_img" src='<?php echo "images/"; read_home('a', 'content_img'); ?>' />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><font size="-1" id="content_comp">
        <?php read_home('a', 'content_comp'); ?>
    </font></td></tr>
</table>
```

What I am trying to accomplish with this is that depending on the button the user clicks, the first perameter of the `read_home()` php function is produced.

```
**html buttons using javascript for php**
    <input type="button" id="s" class="support" onclick="determineDisplay('s');"/>
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="a" class="about" onclick="determineDisplay('a');"/>
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="m" class="mission" onclick="determineDisplay('m');" />
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="v" class="vission" onclick="determineDisplay('v');" />
    <br />
```

Comment: PHP is server side, JS is browser side..

Comment: PHP code is run server-side. Javascript is run client-side. You cannot execute PHP code generated by Javascript. By the time the Javascript runs, PHP is done executing.

Comment: You do realize that this can't work as you have it right? So many things wrong with this question, down to the use of the `<font>` tag.

Comment: Executing PHP on the server which is sent by the client would be a great security risk!

Comment: This sounds like a problem where you'd want to use ajax to query the database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this is to use `ajax`. When you use javascript, it's processing is done on browser side whereas you are trying to produce php based on browser side rendering that's not possible since php is server side PreProcessor.

As @waldol1 said you can use `Ajax` and call async requests for interacting with Server/Database.

Answer (score 3):

> The idea of it is, that when the user clicks a button, that will
>   trigger the type of php script to produce and determine what is
>   accessed from the database.

What you want to do is use ajax.  When the user clicks your button, then you make an async request to your server and then your server can look up in your database and return the results to the browser (It can hand them to a javascript function) without reloading the page.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: nice job referencing ajax. Might i add that a better way to ajax is to use the jQuery library. $.Ajax can be found at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: thanks and I agree that it is easier to use the JQuery library. I just figured that if the OP doesn't understand the difference in server and client side that he needs to read the w3 tutorial or another tutorial before getting into the JQuery docs.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a PreProcesser for Hypertext. Javascript is used after the page has been processed. Hence why you can not insert PHP tags and scripts with Javascript.

Good Luck.

Edit:

As another answer mentioned, you can use Ajax to run scripts after load.
He gave w3schools.com ajax example

Might i suggest using the jQuery Library: http://www.jQuery.com

you can find the api docs at: http://api.jQuery.com