# Php automatically encoding & in Wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

**SOLVED**

Wrapping each instance of the & character in the php with htmlspecialchars() fixed my problem by outputting `&amp;` instead of `&#038;` and allowed the next page to recognize each of the variables correctly!

**/SOLVED/**

I am currently working on a Wordpress site and am trying to create some javascript in the php and then echo it onto the page.  Part of this javascript opens a new window/tab using window.open() and a url I have generated in the php.  However, when I echo the variable containing the url, the all the `&` characters are auto encoded as `&#038;`.

Here is an example of what is happening:

```
...
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = "&";
var url2 = "<?php echo "&"; ?>";
var url3 = <?php echo json_encode("&"); ?>;
var url4 = "<?php echo html_entity_decode("&"); ?>";
var url5 = "<?php echo html_entity_decode("&#038;"); ?>";
</script>
<?php
...
```

Then the actual javascript that is shown when I inspect the element where the script is being inserted is

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = "&#038;";
    var url2 = "&#038;";
    var url3 = "&#038;";
    var url4 = "&#038;";
    var url4 = "&#038;";
</script>
...
```

I have tried urlencode()-ing all of the &'s out of the url, but then $_GET does not recognize them as url variables.

Is this just a Wordpress thing, or is it a php thing?  And, is there anything I can do to make the &'s show up as just &'s?!

**EDIT**

Since there seems to be some confusion on what I'm trying to do, let me explain further.  I am creating a url using php, not javascript.  I am then generating some javascript using php and then echoing that out onto the page.  The above excerpt only shows the problem that I am actually facing.  The actual cod segment looks something like this:

```
$header_element .= "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n"
                . "function validateForm(form) {\n"
                . "\tvar isInvalid = false;\n"
                . $str_all_validation
                . "\tif (!isInvalid) {\n"
                . "\t\trunReport(form);\n"
                . "\t} else {\n"
                . "\talert('You must enter all report parameters.');\n"
                . "\t}\n"
                . "}\n"
                . "function runReport(form) {\n"
                . "\twindow.open('/?page_id=172&PageId=$str_page_id&ReportName=$str_report_name"
                . "$str_all_param, '_blank')\n"
                . "}\n"
                . "</script>";
```

The above outputs correctly aside from having all of the & characters output as `&#038;`.

Comment: it'd be wordpress. PHP will not mangle your output for you like that. Not without you telling it to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [use javascript to produce php in html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923603/use-javascript-to-produce-php-in-html)

Comment: I thought that it must be because I haven't ever had this kind of problem with php before.

Comment: The problem is that Wordpress is running `htmlentities()` on everything you give it.  This is appropriate in most cases, but not if you are injecting JavaScript.  Also, you should always use `json_encode()` around any variable data you use within the context of JavaScript, so the data is escaped correctly.

Comment: Is it possible to suppress this "feature" of Wordpress?

Comment: If you need to have a script on a page with wordpress, you need to use the right function for that. You can find more in the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a usage question of a third party software, here namely how to en-queue  a javascript snippet with Wordpress.

Comment: And as you ask about disabling, here is that on Wordpress Answers: [What's the best plugin for allowing javascript in a post or page?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/21870/178)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your encoding for either your page or your php is mixe up.

try adding this line in your php:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

this should make sure that whatever you output using php is in UTF-8.

And make sure your encoding for your javascrip is the same.

PS You can change the `charset=UTF-8` part for something like `charset=ISO-8859-1` or whatever encoding your using in your javascript.

EDIT:

DO NOT USE THE LAST ANSWER NOT AN ENCODING PROBLEM!!!

try and replace `html_entity_decode()` with the `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: Unfortunately, this had no effect on any of the above output statements.

Comment: I think php is encode in UTF8 but javascript is encode in ISO-8859-1 maybe try adding this:`charset="UTF-8"` to your `<script></script>`

Comment: Like this `<script charset="UTF-8">/*dostuffhere*/</script>`

Comment: The edit solved my problem indirectly!  The output of the function was &amp; instead of &#038;, but this is fine for url encoding, and now the next page can grab each individual $_GET variable!  All I did was wrap any instance of an & character with htmlspecialchars("&") in the php.  Thanks!

Comment: On further inspection, this fix did allow my pages to work correctly, but the variables in get are being stores as amp;PageId, amp;SessionID, etc.  This is not the end of the world, and this answer still fixed my problem, just want to comment here in case someone else comes along and sees this.