# Regarding validation and javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

```
    <div id="maincontent">
     <h1 class="alignLeft">Contact Us</h1>
        <div class="section group">
            <form method="post" action="contact_us.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="ctl01">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKLTM1MzAxMzE5NWRkDpAgZRUlGJo1udX3/PcuUsBXRWcK6P+Zfp5BcrhjhzU=" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['ctl01'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.ctl01;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=fWEJMqFOAVC5WxEaaxa-j7qiwf--JWZEy5_tJqjYisuGhXuGO-exH6fgrpPV6KTKOipS48GWqWV-iAR0dG9CFa7PujIuKsAJ6NmQgyOk_u01&amp;t=635374537680526886" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=TqV9Ufp-3sIQwLSDbJHsdjjs6TCOIUclWAEKbJFvCVSWqQk8Cb7msrfITq2ljFGc8Y852HzFdKrbditLku_MDTXy839FLH9zYwMpYk0cP_Y1&amp;t=635374537680526886" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
if (typeof(ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) return false;
return true;
}
//]]>
</script>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="0829F5A3" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEdAAY5Y5HJq6edLQQMmWbaCfVqVCDn2pfngd5PSl9R1fd0WEMHZh9ZuPBRie2vA/HfoRIiSOTA7Yef34gp3MH3ZlOZegiQmRHLWmb2TjcB9GFfqjzmltaUM7aEAN+g9cP/m13hKXdE9Tt9DxlTtOhzumCPFXkf0nq3NBWVE3/sSt7W7A==" />
</div>

                <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                <h3>Leave us a message</h3>
                <p class="dotted_bg"></p>

                <p align="right" class="marNone"><font class="man_txt">*</font> fields are mandatory</p>
                <label>Name <font class="man_txt">*</font></label>

                    <input name="txtname" type="text" id="txtname" class="textbox" />
                      <span id="reqName" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">Please enter your name!</span>
                                        <span id="regularname" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">Please enter Character only!</span>
                <label>Email  <font class="man_txt">*</font></label>

               <input name="txtEmail" type="text" id="txtEmail" class="textbox" />
                      <span id="reqEmail" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">Please enter your Email!</span>
                      <span id="regulemail" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">Please enter your Email!</span>

                <label>Phone <font class="man_txt">*</font></label>

                <input name="txtphone" type="text" maxlength="15" id="txtphone" class="textbox" />
                <span id="reqphone" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">Please enter your PhoneNo!</span>
                    <span id="rexNumber" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">Please enter numbers only!</span>
                <label>Enquiry Message <font class="man_txt">*</font></label>

                     <textarea name="txtmsg" rows="2" cols="20" id="txtmsg" class="textbox">
</textarea>
                    <span id="reqMsg" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">Please enter your Enquire Message!</span>
<p>
      <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;btnSubmit&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="btnSubmit" class="btn" />
      <input type="reset" class="btn" value="Reset" name="reset"/></p>


                </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var Page_Validators =  new Array(document.getElementById("reqName"), document.getElementById("regularname"), document.getElementById("reqEmail"), document.getElementById("regulemail"), document.getElementById("reqphone"), document.getElementById("rexNumber"), document.getElementById("reqMsg"));
//]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var reqName = document.all ? document.all["reqName"] : document.getElementById("reqName");
reqName.controltovalidate = "txtname";
reqName.errormessage = "Please enter your name!";
reqName.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
reqName.initialvalue = "";
var regularname = document.all ? document.all["regularname"] : document.getElementById("regularname");
regularname.controltovalidate = "txtname";
regularname.errormessage = "Please enter Character only!";
regularname.evaluationfunction = "RegularExpressionValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
regularname.validationexpression = "^[a-zA-Z\'.\\s]{1,40}$";
var reqEmail = document.all ? document.all["reqEmail"] : document.getElementById("reqEmail");
reqEmail.controltovalidate = "txtEmail";
reqEmail.errormessage = "Please enter your Email!";
reqEmail.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
reqEmail.initialvalue = "";
var regulemail = document.all ? document.all["regulemail"] : document.getElementById("regulemail");
regulemail.controltovalidate = "txtEmail";
regulemail.errormessage = "Please enter your Email!";
regulemail.evaluationfunction = "RegularExpressionValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
regulemail.validationexpression = "\\w+([-+.\']\\w+)*@\\w+([-.]\\w+)*\\.\\w+([-.]\\w+)*";
var reqphone = document.all ? document.all["reqphone"] : document.getElementById("reqphone");
reqphone.controltovalidate = "txtphone";
reqphone.errormessage = "Please enter your PhoneNo!";
reqphone.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
reqphone.initialvalue = "";
var rexNumber = document.all ? document.all["rexNumber"] : document.getElementById("rexNumber");
rexNumber.controltovalidate = "txtphone";
rexNumber.errormessage = "Please enter numbers only!";
rexNumber.evaluationfunction = "RegularExpressionValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
rexNumber.validationexpression = "^[0-9]+$";
var reqMsg = document.all ? document.all["reqMsg"] : document.getElementById("reqMsg");
reqMsg.controltovalidate = "txtmsg";
reqMsg.errormessage = "Please enter your Enquire Message!";
reqMsg.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
reqMsg.initialvalue = "";
//]]>
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var Page_ValidationActive = false;
if (typeof(ValidatorOnLoad) == "function") {
    ValidatorOnLoad();
}
function ValidatorOnSubmit() {
    if (Page_ValidationActive) {
        return ValidatorCommonOnSubmit();
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
</form>
```

I have given my code here. I have migrated this page to wordpress. Validation on clicking the submit button doesn't work, but is redirecting to other page instead. I am getting the error msg as

```
SyntaxError: illegal character


...ypeof(ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" &#038;&#038; ValidatorOnSubmit() == false...


?p=1704 (line 166, col 45)
```

Could anyone of you please help me get rid of this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Php automatically encoding & in Wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366213/php-automatically-encoding-in-wordpress)

Comment: please check the above link, it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But i dont get an output. myself getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `&#038;&#038;` with `&&`.

Your code got jumbled during migration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have used && in the code as u said. While migrating in wordpress i am getting &#038;&#038; instead of &&.                      function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
if (typeof(ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) return false;
return true;

Comment: Also on clicking submit button its getting redirected to the other page. will u pls help me by giving the reason and also some solutions about the mistakes made by me.

Comment: Sorry. R u asking about the above page

Comment: The problem is that while migrating to WP, the `&` got html encoded. You need to replace them with `&`. I guess you can edit code on WP. How did you migrate?

Comment: Since i am very beginner to this wordpress for the past few days i was working on wordpress. with the steps given in google. i dont have much idea about the wordpress. so u pls help me by giving some solutions

Comment: I have migrated the page by using the plugin HTML import

Comment: Hi anurag i have edited in wp code as && but i am getting the same error. In brower its again showing the same error

Comment: one more doubt if i edit the code in wp as u said my css is also affecting in that page. can u pls explain y. Also on changing && in wp code on running its again changed to &#038;

Comment: @Vidyut is it possible to share the link of your word page site?
I can't say much about WP since I'm not too familiar with it. I have marked the question with WP tag, someone will definitely help you out.

Comment: since i am working in local host. I am unable to share the requested link

Comment: Also thanks for the link. I have tried with that link but i am getting the same error